# Where to find API reference of NestJS

Tags: nestjs

Where can I find the API reference of NestJS? I can not find a good resource, the content of https://docs.nestjs.com/ is all about guidance, but the detailed API reference was not included.

Comment: [there's a WIP PR on this](https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/pull/413). I don't think you'll find any other references other then that.

Answer (score 2):

https://api-references-nestjs.netlify.app/api

This is the beta version API document. I've got this URL from https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/pull/413